# Redirecting user to app service instance according to location

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have multiple instances of my application using different Azure app service plans according to location.
Is it possible to redirect users to a different app service instance depending on their location? (i.e. a user from Spain will be redirected to the "West Europe" app service while a person it USA will be redirected to the "North America" app service instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do with Azure Traffic Manager with the [`Geographic traffic-routing method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#geographic)

From docs,

> Traffic Manager profiles can be configured to use the Geographic
>   routing method so that users are directed to specific endpoints
>   (Azure, External or Nested) based on which geographic location their
>   DNS query originates from. This empowers Traffic Manager customers to
>   enable scenarios where knowing a user’s geographic region and routing
>   them based on that is important.